# In a React TS component, how do I pass optional props not defined in the interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following TS React component (**MyButton.tsx**):

```
import React from 'react'

interface MyButtonProps {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[],
  className?: string,
  variant?: 'big-button' | 'medium-button' | 'small-button'
}

const MyButton = ({
  children,
  className,
  variant
}: MyButtonProps) => {
  let baseClassName: string = 'my-button'
  if (variant != null) {
    baseClassName += ' ' + variant
  }

  return (
    <button
      className={baseClassName + ' ' + className}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}

export default MyButton
```

It's a fairly simple component to understand. I can use it in the following way:

```
<MyButton variant='big-button'>Click Here</MyButton>
```

It works fine. However, ideally I would like to pass in props to this component that are not defined in the Interface for the `MyButtonProps`. For example, I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
<MyButton variant='small-button' type="reset" disabled>Reset Form</MyButton>
```

The `type` and `disabled` props are normal HTML attributes, but TS throws an error at me because I have not defined them in the Interface. How can I solve this? I remember seeing the `...` operator for a use case similar to this, but can't find it anymore. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That isn't how it works. The interface of the component is what it is, you can fix the interface but it can only use props it knows about, and it doesn't know what to do with those props.

Comment: @JaredSmith Fair enough. So this needs to be done without the interface then?

Comment: No you need to change the interface to include the other properties. See Konrad's answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
interface MyButtonProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[],
  className?: string,
  variant?: 'big-button' | 'medium-button' | 'small-button'
}
```

```
Try this:

 const MyButton = (
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[],
  className?: string,
  variant?: 'big-button' | 'medium-button' | 'small-button',
  ...others: any[]
 )
const MyButton = ({
  children,
  className,
  variant,
  ...props
}: MyButtonProps) => {
  let baseClassName: string = 'my-button'
  if (variant != null) {
    baseClassName += ' ' + variant
  }

  return (
    <button
      className={baseClassName + ' ' + className}
      { ...props }
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: That only works if OP owns the compnent/interface

Comment: It's called `MyButton` I though OP has claims for it

Comment: Perhaps. We'll see.

Comment: I get the following when I try this: `The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2363)
Property 'HTMLProps' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.ts(2339)`. I apologise, I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Sorry wrong syntax, fixed

Comment: This works now, but how do I actually use the props pass? For instance, I can pass the `disabled` prop now, but how do I actually apply it to my component?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
 const MyButton = (
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[],
  className?: string,
  variant?: 'big-button' | 'medium-button' | 'small-button',
  ...others: any[]
 )
```

So this should work:

```
 const MyButton = (
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[],
  className?: string,
  variant?: 'big-button' | 'medium-button' | 'small-button',
  ...others: any[]
 ) => {
  let baseClassName: string = 'my-button'
  if (variant != null) {
    baseClassName += ' ' + variant
  }

  return (
    <button {...others}
      className={baseClassName + ' ' + className}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}

export default MyButton
```

Now you can use those extra props by simply spreading them in jsx element like this `<button {...others}/>`.

Example:

```
<MyButton className="blah" disabled/>
```

The above `disabled` will be applied to `<button/>` as follows:

```
<button disabled/>
```

Comment: Would you mind writing out the full module please? How do I use this `const` to create the actual component?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to edit this